# Parsing PPPoE packets with dpkt

Tags: python, parsing, pppoe, dpkt

I am trying to retrieve 5-tuples information from a list of pcap files using the dpkt library. To parse the PPPoE packets with VLAN tags, I write codes like this(for test only):

```
import dpkt
import socket

def decode(pc):
    for ts, pkt in pc:
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)
        pppoe = dpkt.pppoe.PPPoE(eth.data)
        ip = pppoe.data
        if ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP:
            udp = ip.data
            yield(ip.src, udp.sport, ip.dst, udp.dport, ip.v)
        else: pass

def test():
    pc = dpkt.pcap.Reader(open('epon.pcap','rb'))
    for src, sport, dst, dport, ip_version in decode(pc):
        print "from", socket.inet_ntoa(src),":",sport, " to ",socket.inet_ntoa(dst),":",dport

test()
```

It turns out error which means the parsing is wrong:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'p'
```

So what should the correct code be like? I'm a Python beginner and the dpkt source code really puzzles me a lot...

Comment: What are you expecting 'p' to be? An IP address? IP version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture you have has a vlan within a vlan (stacked vlan).

Without modifying the dpkt library you will need to parse the second VLAN manually.

Another problem you will have is the payload of pppoe is ppp not ip.

You can change your code to something like this:

```
import struct
```

...

```
def decode(pc):
for ts, pkt in pc:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)
    if eth.type == dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_8021Q:
         eth.tag, eth.type = struct.unpack('>HH', eth.data[:4])
         eth.data = eth.data[4:]
    pppoe = dpkt.pppoe.PPPoE(eth.data)
    ppp = pppoe.data
    ip = ppp.ip
    if ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP:
        udp = ip.data
        yield(ip.src, udp.sport, ip.dst, udp.dport, ip.v)
    else: pass
```

Comment: It does work! Thanks. However, the program returns `TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string` after parsing 200 udp packets from the file [test2.pcap](https://app.box.com/s/xlpiydclprou2igoc8y57376oral4cik) It also failed for other large files after parsing different number of packets. What's the problem?

Comment: I did not get such an error parsing that with this code. But it does look like not all frames are with VLANs.